# Why valgrind shows leaks, even when the vector containing dynamically allocated objects is freed?

Tags: c++, linux, vector, valgrind

I have allocated a vector on the heap using new:

```
std::vector<t*> *vec = new std::vector<t*>;
```

This vector contains class objects, of a class "t", these class objects are created using new

```
t *ptr1 = new t();
t *ptr2 = new t();
t *ptr3 = new t();
t *ptr4 = new t();
```

Now when i delete the vector, it's expected that all these objects which are added to it should get destroyed as well, i mean:

```
std::vector<t*> *vec = new std::vector<t*>;
 vec->push_back(ptr1);
 vec->push_back(ptr2);
 vec->push_back(ptr3);
 vec->push_back(ptr4);
```

memory pointed by ptr1, ptr2, ptr3, ptr4 should get freed as well.

But Valgrind shows this as a leak !!!
Is Valgrind faulty?

```
==15634==
==15634== HEAP SUMMARY:
==15634==     in use at exit: 48 bytes in 8 blocks
==15634==   total heap usage: 12 allocs, 4 frees, 128 bytes allocated
==15634==
==15634== LEAK SUMMARY:
==15634==    definitely lost: 32 bytes in 4 blocks
==15634==    indirectly lost: 16 bytes in 4 blocks
==15634==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15634==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15634==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15634== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==15634==
==15634== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==15634== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Here is the full program for everyone's reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class t
{
int *ptr;
public:
  t()
  {
    cout << "t's constructor" << endl;
    ptr = new int(50);
  }
 ~t()
  {
    cout << "t's destructor called" << endl;
    delete ptr;
  }

  void func()
  {
     cout << "This is class t's function" << endl;
  }

};

//void func(int *ptr, t* ptr1)
void func(t* ptr1)
{
 //delete ptr;
 delete ptr1;
}

int main( )
{
 //int *ptr;

 t *ptr1 = new t();
 t *ptr2 = new t();
 t *ptr3 = new t();
 t *ptr4 = new t();
 //ptr =new int(20);
 //func(ptr, ptr1);
 //func(ptr1);

 std::vector<t*> *vec = new std::vector<t*>;
 vec->push_back(ptr1);
 vec->push_back(ptr2);
 vec->push_back(ptr3);
 vec->push_back(ptr4);

 delete vec;
 //delete ptr1; ===============> Are these required? Shouldn't delete vec take care?
// delete ptr2;
 //delete ptr3;
 //delete ptr4;

}
```

Comment: C++ is not java, avoid `new` whenever possible, the language allows you to use types without dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Now when i delete the vector, it's expected that all these objects which are added to it should get destroyed as well

*They are.* You added pointers, and the pointers will be destroyed.

That says nothing about the things the pointers point to, though. In short, your assumption is wrong.

Your options:

- `delete` each pointee before destroying the vector
- use smart pointers
- stop using pointers! stop using dynamic allocation!
  `std::vector<t>` should be fine in the majority of cases.

Comment: I disagree with your last point. It becomes way too performance-consuming as soon as what you store is a bit big (large class/struct), or when you need to copy the vector around. I always prefer pointers inside my vectors.

Comment: @Ely perhaps you should not be passing the vector around. Perhaps you should be passing a `const` reference around.

Comment: @Mgetz while it's easy to pass a vector as a const reference, it's much trickier when you need to return a vector created in a sub-function. I was mainly referring to these situations.

Comment: @Ely return a vector created in a sub-function is not expensive because of move semantics and Return value optimization.

Comment: @Ely: _"I always prefer pointers inside my vectors."_ Well I'm sorry to sound rude but that is very bad practice and sounds like inexperience. You should prefer pass-by-value and you can get it to be perfectly efficient. Storing pointers in containers creates a mess that isn't worth it at all.

Comment: I like to std::move it std::move it. I like to std::move it std::move it.

Comment: Unfortunately, some objects object, (sorry), to being moved.

Comment: Vectors move just fine, though.

Comment: @All I just documented myself on NRVO and other optimizations, indeed returning a vector doesn't seem like a problem performance-wise. Thanks for the insight, I'll go to sleep smarter.

Comment: @Ely: The problem here isn't that you didn't know NRVO. The problem is that you didn't profile it and find out what the performance problem actually *was*. If you did, you would not have needed to know NRVO to know that it was not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

When the verctor is destroyed, it destroyed only the memory allocated by the vector. That mean, verctor needs internal structures to keep the t* that you inserted. That memory is definitly deleted by the desctor destructor. But the values that you have “newed” are not freed by the vector.

You are the responsible person for deleting those memory.